# What is the correct way to use node dependent paths in Netbeans?

Tags: linux, maven, netbeans, maven-2, netbeans-7

I'm using Netbeans 7.1.2 on Linux (bash) with Maven2.

Depending on what computer on the network I log in to, the path to maven varies.  It is either /gfs/blah/maven or /nfs/blah/maven.
I have an environment variable to take care of this on the command line.

However, I am apparently not allowed to use an environment variable under Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Maven -> Maven Home

What is the correct was of handling this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Netbeans in a Gnome session?

Comment: Yes, mostly I'm using Gnome, but occasionally icewm.

Comment: Ok so try to put `export YOURVAR="your_path"
` in the file ~/.gnomerc, and restart the session (it's like the .bashrc file)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it seems the problem is getting NetBeans to accept the use of any environment variable in the setup paths.  If I try to put ${MY_ENV_VAR}/lib/blah into either the ant location or the maven location, Netbeans modifies the result to add the Netbeans location first, as in /my/netbeans/loc/${MY_ENV_VAR}/lib/blah, which of course it cannot find.  If I give the location /${MY_ENV_VAR}/lib/blah, then it doesn't prepend the Netbeans location, but it still doesn't find the location.

Comment: Ok did you try to set the var as I've suggested? What print `echo ${MY_ENV_VAR}`?

Comment: Yes, I tried it with a test variable, but the echo returns blank.  The echo does return the actual ENV variable correctly, though.

Comment: Ofc the envvar in .gnomerc will not be displayed from a Terminal but will be accessible from an app( like Netbeans) launch from Gnome. Btw I just realize that, in netbeans, you can't edit the path but just choose it with a filechooser. And I don't know if you can set the path elsewhere. So I don't see any solution that can fit sorry...

Comment: Thanks very much for looking, Alain.